# ROS_PACKAGE_PATH dont include kinetic/stacks

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, stacks, ros-package-path

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have Ubuntu 64b 16.04 and ROS Kinectic.

echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
/home/viclinux/catkin_ws/src:/opt/ros/kinetic/share

as you see, I do not have .../kinetic/stacks folder. Is it important? What is wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250032/ros_package_path-dont-include-kinetic/stacks/) by [marilia15](https://answers.ros.org/users/5506/marilia15/) on ROS Answers with karma: 104 on 2016-12-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know when exactly the `stacks` folder actually vanished, but it does not exist anymore at least since indigo. So it is not needed in the package path anymore.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-12-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [marilia15](https://answers.ros.org/users/5506/marilia15/) on 2016-12-14**:
it would be great to update the tutorial then
http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment
How can we advice the admin?

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-12-14**:
You can register and then edit it youself. I've done this for now: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/catkin/CreateWorkspace
Just to be sure: @William is there still any case where you could have `/opt/ros/kinetic/stacks`?

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2016-12-20**:
I would guess it might have disappeared when we stopped building binaries for rosbuild packages. Perhaps it would exist if you manually created a binary package for stack of rosbuild packages, but I'm not sure. @Dirk Thomas